# null pointer ANDROID

Tags: android, class

I have this code, and I have a problem in this line: draView1.getNumMallas(); its value is 0 here, however I checked it in another class and this value and it isn't 0, any idea? I want to create that number of buttons dynamically

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ControladorResuelto extends Activity {


public ControladorView drawView1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      setContentView(R.layout.panel_resuelto);

      drawView1 = (ControladorView)findViewById(R.id.drawing1);

      setup();




  //  LinearLayout buttonsLayout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutUp1);

/*    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Buttin "+(i+1));
      //  button.set....other attributes
        buttonsLayout.addView(button);
    }*/

}

private void setup() {
        LinearLayout buttonsLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutUp);



        Log.e (Integer.toString(drawView1.getNumMallas()),"nMallas Resuelto");

    //LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for(int i=0;i<drawView1.getNumMallas();i++){
        Button button = new Button(this);

        Button button1 = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Malla "+(i+1));
      //  button.set....other attributes
        buttonsLayout.addView(button);
        buttonsLayout.addView(button1);
    }

}
```

this is a part of my layout, in XML and com.example.nuevo.ControladorView is a SurfaceView:

```
<com.example.nuevo.ControladorView
    android:id="@+id/drawing1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.83" />
```

the logcat
http://oi61.tinypic.com/fku13o.jpg

Comment: `drawView1` is null. post the relevant layout code `panel_resuelto.xml`

Comment: this is a part of my layout, in XML and com.example.nuevo.ControladorView is a SurfaceView: <com.example.nuevo.ControladorView
        android:id="@+id/drawing1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.83" />

Comment: That XML snippet is part of res/layout/panel_resuelto? Please verify in the debugger that `drawView1` is `null`. (Like Raghunandan commented, that's the only way that `drawView1.getNumMallas()` can throw a `NullPointerException`.) It might help if you posted the logcat output of the crash.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace

Comment: pls add stacktrace from logcat & your full layout file!

Comment: http://oi61.tinypic.com/fku13o.jpg